# Where i can see the font code of scipy special chndtr and chndtrix?

Tags: python, github, scipy

I am navigating in the github of scipy but I couldn't find the definition code of scipy.special.chndtr. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like these are wrappers functions:

```
  "chndtr": {
        "cdf_wrappers.h": {
            "cdfchn1_wrap": "ddd->d"
        }
    },
    "chndtrix": {
        "cdf_wrappers.h": {
            "cdfchn2_wrap": "ddd->d"
        }
    },
```

and you can find `cdfchn1_wrap` under  `scipy/special/cdf_wrappers.c`.

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/special/cdf_wrappers.c

the same thing with `chndtrix` , you can find it in the same file under `cdfchn2_wrap`

Comment: thanks, i din't know that follow this code was so difficult